# Preferred caching strategy for data-driven applications on mobile devices

Tags: mobile, cloud, soa, offline-caching

What is the preferred strategy for creating a mobile application that relies on data to be moved to/from a cloud-based service (thus requiring connectivity)?

What mechanisms are typically employed to ensure synchronization while connectivity can be less than stable?

Are all potential write operations queued locally and recover gracefully from terminated uploads?

Are most downloads/data queries just re-executed when applications are brought back in scope or regain connectivity after losing it for a while?

Specific guidance as well as training materials/study resources are acceptable!